# How to add support for custom languages in Flutter using the 'intl' package?

Tags: flutter, localization, intl

I am developing a Flutter app and want to add support in my application for regional languages of India like Hindi, Gujarati, Tamil, etc. I am using the `intl` package (version **0.18.0**) for internationalization and localization.

Could anyone provide steps to execute to add custom languages (Hindi, Gujarati, Tamil, etc) using the `intl` package?

Specifically, I am confused about the naming convension for **.arb** files.

I am try to adding the package [intl: ^0.18.1](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) but not found any guidelines in the official documentation regarding custom localization.

Answer (score 0):

Frist create a custom  delegate similar to GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate and GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate

```
    class DemoLocalization {
      DemoLocalization(this.locale);
    
      final Locale locale;
      late Map<String, String> _localizedValues = {}; // Initialize with an empty map
    
      static DemoLocalization of(BuildContext context) {
        //
        return Localizations.of<DemoLocalization>(context, DemoLocalization)??DemoLocalization(new Locale('en'));
      }
    
    
      Future<void> load() async {
        String jsonStringValues =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lib/l10n/app_${locale.languageCode}.arb');
        Map<String, dynamic> mappedJson = json.decode(jsonStringValues);
        print(jsonStringValues);
        _localizedValues =mappedJson.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
      }
    
      String translate(String key) {
        print(key);
        return _localizedValues[key]??"en";
      }
    
      // static member to have simple access to the delegate from Material App
      static const LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> delegate =
      _DemoLocalizationsDelegate();
    }
```

After that Creating delegate for DemoLocalization

```
    class _DemoLocalizationsDelegate
        extends LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> {
      const _DemoLocalizationsDelegate();
    
      @override
      bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
        return ['en','nn' ].contains(locale.languageCode);
      }
    
      @override
      Future<DemoLocalization> load(Locale locale) async {
        DemoLocalization localization = DemoLocalization(locale);
        await localization.load();
        return localization;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> old) => false;
    }
```

Finally you can use

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
    import 'demo_localization.dart'; // Import your localization classes
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          localeResolutionCallback: (deviceLocale, supportedLocales) {
            for (var locale in supportedLo`enter code here`cales) {
              if (locale.languageCode == deviceLocale!.languageCode &&
                  locale.countryCode == deviceLocale.countryCode) {
                return deviceLocale;
              }
            }
            return supportedLocales.first;
          },
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            DemoLocalization.delegate, // Use the custom delegate
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: const [
            Locale('en'),
            Locale('nn'),
          ],
          locale: const Locale('nn'),
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final localizations = DemoLocalization.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(localizations.translate('hello')),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Text(
              localizations.translate('hello'),
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).